# Exibir usuário logado no sistema C#

Tags: c#

Consegui pegar o usuário logado através do texto digitado no `TextBox`.
Mas eu não quero o usuário, quero o nome de usuário.
Exemplo banco de dados:

```
id = 1
nome_usuario = Administrador
usuario = admin
senha = 1234
nivel_acesso = 1
```

Quero pegar o dado `nome_usuario` e exibir em uma Label no formulário principal da minha aplicação.

Esse é meu código do formulário `frmLogin`

```
public partial class frmLogin : Form
{

    public bool logado = false;
    public static string usuarioConectado;

    public frmLogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnEntrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conexao = "Data Source=DESKTOP-AJLR3DB\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DBGestor;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conexao);
        SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE usuario = @usuario and senha = @senha", conn);

        comando.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUsuario.Text;
        comando.Parameters.Add("@senha", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtSenha.Text;

        conn.Open();

        int i = (int)comando.ExecuteScalar();

        if (i > 0)
        {
            logado = true;
            usuarioConectado = reader["nome_funcionario"].ToString();
            this.Dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            logado = false;
            MessageBox.Show("Usuário e/ou Senha inválido.");
        }
        conn.Close();
    }

    private void txtSenha_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) && e.KeyChar != (char)8)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Este campo aceita apenas números.");
        }
    }

    private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Preciso saber como atribuir o valor `nome_usuario` a variável `usuarioConectado`
Esse é meu código do formulário `frmPricipal`

```
private void frmPrincipal_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblUsuario.Text = "Olá, " + frmLogin.usuarioConectado;
}
```

**Consegui resolver o problema, código atualizado.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ler valores, você pode usar o `ExecuteReader`, veja como ficaria(acompanhe os comentários):

```
var conn = new SqlConnection(conexao);
var comando = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM funcionarios WHERE usuario = @usuario and senha = @senha", conn);

comando.Parameters.Add("@usuario", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUsuario.Text;
comando.Parameters.Add("@senha", SqlDbType.Int).Value = txtSenha.Text;

conn.Open();

var reader = comando.ExecuteReader(); //Executa o comando

if (reader.Read()) //Lê uma linha (false se não tiver linhas para ler)
{
    logado = true;
    usuarioConectado = reader["nome_usuario"].ToString(); //Pega o valor de "nome_usuario" da linha que foi lida
    this.Dispose();
}
else
{
    logado = false;
    MessageBox.Show("Usuário e/ou Senha inválido.");
}
conn.Close();
```

Para mexer com banco de dados, sempre prefiri usar o [`using`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Comment: Ele está retornando o seguinte erro `Não é possível converter implicitamente tipo "object" em "string". Existe uma conversão explícita (há uma conversão ausente?`

Comment: @Giovani Faltou o ToString. Editei a resposta, tente agr.

Comment: Compilo a aplicação, digito usuário e senha, dá esse erro `System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'nome_usuario'`.

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema, no `SqlCommand` está `SELECT COUNT(*)`, coloquei apenas `SELECT *` e deu certo. Obrigado pela atenção